# Calling a Oracle Service through JSON inside another JSON service call

Tags: javascript, html, json, service, oracle11g

I am using JSON to call a oracle service which fetches data (a list) from Server side. Inside the JSON call, I iterate through the list in a FOR loop and I need to call another web service to fetch some data related to each row in the list. I have written that logic in a JavaScript function, and I am calling that function inside the FOR loop.
The issue I am facing is, for example, if original list consists of a 2 items, then the FOR loop is executing 2 times first, and then the function is called 2 times together.

What I want is that every time the loop is iterated, the java script method should be called in the same iteration, fetch the values, I should be able to perform actions based on the results fetched, and it should be repeated for next iterations.
The javascript code is given below. Sequence of alert I am want is: 1,3,2,4,1,3,2,4,5.
Sequence of alert which I am getting is: 1,4,1,4,3,2,3,2,5

```
var url = "idcplg?IdcService=AJAX_SERVICE&Id=" + Id;
$.getJSON(escapeCachingForUrl(url), function(data){

for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
  alert("1");
    //some code written
    myMethod(data,function(result){
    alert("2");
    // Need to operate on result
    });
    alert("4");       
    }
    alert("5");
});

function myMethod(data,callback){
var url = "idcplg?IdcService=AJAX_ANOTHER_SERVICE";
                $.getJSON(escapeCachingForUrl(url), { 
                                data : data
                                }, function(data){
                                                alert("3");
                                                callback(data);
                                });
}
```

Comment: I think the problem has to do with the A in AJAX. When you call `myMethod` from the `for` loop, it is not guaranteed that the `$getJSON` call will finish before the next 'myMethod' is called and completed. Your trying to make an Asynchronous function work Synchronously...

Comment: yes, probably. So is there any way to achieve what i need?

Comment: Certainly, but you would have to do away with the `for` loop and keep up with the array index manually. When you call `myMethod`, should you be sending all of the `data`, or just the current index `data[i]`?

Comment: just the current index data[i]